# Declaring a global array extension leads to compiler error

Tags: typescript

I want to write that array-extension in TypeScript:

```
if (!Array.prototype.remove) {
    Array.prototype.remove = function <T>(elem: T): T[] {
        return this.filter(e => e !== elem);
    }
}
```

so I need to declare an interface for it. There's nothing in that file, just:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        remove(elem: T): Array<T>;
    }
}
```

but the compiler cries:

> TS2669: Augumentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations

funny is, when I add this line before:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

(what has nothing to do with the Array or something - jQuery is not used here), it's okay for the compiler.

Any idea what is going on here? And how can I declare the interface without adding the reference to jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript a file with an import/export at top-level is treaded as a module, while a file without import/export at top-level is treaded as a script - and this is already in global scope.

So if we want to define it in global, we either add an import, so it's a module and we can define it as global - or we just remove the "define global" and it's executed as script in gobal scope.

So it's enough to set this as content in the file:

```
interface Array<T> {
    remove(elem: T): Array<T>;
}
```